# Convert monthly pay data to weekly using complete and fill in dplyr

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr

I have data on worker pay and some workers are paid monthly and others weekly. I would like to combine the data into a panel by worker and week (of year). To do that, I need to expand the monthly rows.

The data look like:

```
pay_data <- tibble(worker="Jim", start=ymd("2020-1-3"), end=ymd("2020-2-2"), rate=10, hours=50, wages=rate*hours) %>% 
  mutate(f_week=week(start), l_week=week(end))  

# A tibble: 1 x 8
  worker start      end         rate hours wages f_week l_week
  <chr>  <date>     <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Jim    2020-01-03 2020-02-02    10    50   500      1      5
```

Is there a way to use complete, fill or any other dplyr function to get the data to look like the below?

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  worker  week  rate hours  wage
  <chr>  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Jim        1    10    50   500
2 Jim        2    10    50   500
3 Jim        3    10    50   500
4 Jim        4    10    50   500
5 Jim        5    10    50   500
```

(I would then of course divide the amounts to put them all in common units).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another `tidyverse` way would be :

```
library(tidyverse)

pay_data %>%
  mutate(week = map2(f_week, l_week, seq)) %>%
  unnest(week) %>%
  select(worker, rate:wages, week)

#  worker  rate hours wages  week
#  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#1 Jim       10    50   500     1
#2 Jim       10    50   500     2
#3 Jim       10    50   500     3
#4 Jim       10    50   500     4
#5 Jim       10    50   500     5
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak! Do you know of a way to create this week variable in a more memory efficient way than a huge character variable? The data I am working with are very large and some paychecks are paid annually, so in that case it is going to create a character variable of length >50.

Comment: week isn't a character variable. It is an integer.

Comment: After the map2 step it is a long character variable, I believe. But yes it is an integer at the end. Does it not consume memory if it is within the pipe? I also was having trouble scaling this up to the full data set with reasonable run time just in case you have suggestions on that front. Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

A `tidyverse` approach making use of `tidyr::separate_rows` may look like so. To make the data more interesting I added data for a second worker.

```r
library(tidyverse)

tbl %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(weeks = paste(seq(f_week, l_week, by = 1), collapse = ", ")) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  separate_rows(weeks) %>% 
  select(-ends_with("_week"), -start, -end)
#> # A tibble: 13 x 5
#>    worker  rate hours wages weeks
#>    <chr>  <int> <int> <int> <chr>
#>  1 Jim       10    50   500 1    
#>  2 Jim       10    50   500 2    
#>  3 Jim       10    50   500 3    
#>  4 Jim       10    50   500 4    
#>  5 Jim       10    50   500 5    
#>  6 John      20   100  1000 1    
#>  7 John      20   100  1000 2    
#>  8 John      20   100  1000 3    
#>  9 John      20   100  1000 4    
#> 10 John      20   100  1000 5    
#> 11 John      20   100  1000 6    
#> 12 John      20   100  1000 7    
#> 13 John      20   100  1000 8
```

**DATA**

```r
tbl <- read.table(text="worker start      end         rate hours wages f_week l_week
1 Jim    2020-01-03 2020-02-02    10    50   500      1      5\n
2 John    2020-01-03 2020-02-02    20    100   1000      1      8", header = TRUE)
tbl
#>   worker      start        end rate hours wages f_week l_week
#> 1    Jim 2020-01-03 2020-02-02   10    50   500      1      5
#> 2   John 2020-01-03 2020-02-02   20   100  1000      1      8
```

Comment: Stefan -- do you have any advice on how I could handle the case where the start and end dates cross years? So:

`tbl <- read.table(text="worker start      end         rate hours wages f_week l_week
1 Jim    2019-12-18 2020-01-18    10    50   500      1      5\n
2 John    2020-01-03 2020-02-02    20    100   1000      1      8", header = TRUE)`

Comment: My confusion is that R does not seem to have a native "weekly date" storage format

Comment: So I believe I resolved that by simply creating a new dataset with custom week_ids based on the cross of week x year. 

I was curious, however, if you knew of a more memory efficient way to create the "weeks" variable that you have in your code. The data I am working with are very large and sometimes pay checks can cover a whole year (52 weeks), so this creates a massive variable storage wise.

Comment: Hi Benny. I just did some benchmarks. And if efficiency does matter for you I would recommend to use the approach proposed by @RonakShah in his answer. His approach is not only more memory efficient but also faster than my approach.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help Stefan, I appreciate it

Comment: Hi Stefan. Curious if in your benchmarking you know how much memory Ronak's operation consumes within the pipe relative to the size of the input data. I am cleaning a dataset that is ~15GB on a server with 64GB of RAM (although there are some other people using the server as well). My code is failing on this exact step. Is it possible that this step would consume more than twice as much memory as the initial dataset? If so, I might need to break the data into chunks and do this successively (any packages to automate that?). Thanks again for your help

Comment: Hm. I'm afraid I can't help you on that. I benchmarked only an example dataset. And have to admit that I'm no expert on the internals of R or dplyr/tidyr memory management.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#Code
pay_data <- pay_data[rep(seq_len(nrow(pay_data)), unique(pay_data$l_week)),
         c('worker','rate','hours','wages')]
pay_data$week <- 1:nrow(pay_data)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  worker  rate hours wages  week
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1 Jim       10    50   500     1
2 Jim       10    50   500     2
3 Jim       10    50   500     3
4 Jim       10    50   500     4
5 Jim       10    50   500     5
```